# How do I upload a blob to google drive using Google API in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-api, fetch-api

I have been meaning to fetch a .docx file from a certain server using node js' fetch api and store it on google drive using google API for nodejs. However, the .docx file when fetched comes as a blob file and I am uncertain about how to deal with blobs and upload them on drive.

Here's my code so far:

```
app.get('/getData', (req, res) => {
    const resp = await fetch(some_url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + some_access_token,
      },
    });
    const dataBlob = await resp.blob();
    const dataBlobText = await dataBlob.text();

    const data = {};
    data.name = 'file.docx';
    data.mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    data.body = dataBlob; // is this valid??

    const driveResponse = await uploadFileToDrive(data);
    console.log(driveResponse);
    res.json(driveResponse)
});
```

Here's `uploadFileToDrive` function:

```
async function uploadFileToDrive(data) {
  try {
    const authClient = await authorize();
    const response = await drive.files.create({
      requestBody: {
        name: data.name,
        mimeType: data.mimeType,
      },
      media: {
        mimeType: data.mimeType,
        body: data.body, // not sure .....
      },
      auth: authClient,
    });
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

I have tried the above code and it does not work. After running, I get an error, `part.body.pipe is not a function`. I am very new to this, any help appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between Node.js and Google Apps Script from `I have been meaning to fetch a .docx file from a certain server using node js' fetch api and store it on google drive using google apps script.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am creating an express app that fetches documents from salesforce, and then saves that document in google drive. I am able to fetch the document from salesforce through their rest API using JS's built in fetch function(alternative for axios), and the fetched document comes to me as a blob. I am unsure how to convert a blob to docx again and save it in google drive. Probably if some one could lead me with `how to convert a blob to docx`, I might be able to solve the issue. Sorry that my question wasn't clear.  @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between Node.js and Google Apps Script from your reply. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to try to understand the relationship between Node.js and Google Apps Script in your question.

Comment: Here's the google documentation for Google Apps Script api that I have been following developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/nodejs for docs file and developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads explains how you can save documents to drive from nodejs. I probably should call it GoogleApi than google app script, my bad @Tanaike